# Git - how to allow only authentified SSH user

Tags: git, ssh

I have installed Git on a test server to which only I have access via SSH.
But now with Git I found out that anyone can clone and push stuff if he knows the IP and the path of my Git project.

What can I do to grant "Git access" only to authentified SSH user?

Comment: What protocol do you think people are able to access your repository under?

Answer (score 2):

The actual GIT daemon (implementing the git: protocol) doesn't have any authentication.  If you instead configure yourself to just use the ssh protocol for access and don't enable the daemon then everything is as secure as ssh (so only authenticated users can access the repo).

Answer (score 2):

Since you've installed git with ssh access alone, only people whose ssh keys are configured will be able to push commits to your repos on your test server.

The repo will be publicly accessible for reads, only if the repo exists in a publicly accessible directory. So, till you host your code in a private directory, your code is safe.

Comment: I want to use GIT for a web app. So I took the folder in which the app is and turned it into a repository. So yes, it is publicly accessible.
I can access the server via SSH by using my private key and a password. But if I do git clone user@IP on my local computer I can successfuly clone the rep to my computer (and later push as well) without being asked for any password.

Comment: @JohannesN You can add a rewrite/ignore rule for `.git` in your webserver config then. That way, no one will be able to access your .git folder, and hence won't be able to clone it publicly.

Comment: I added a htaccess to the .git folder: 

Order deny,allow
Deny from all

But I can still clone the Rep with no restrictions.

Comment: @almo Were you able to resolve this? Don't forget to accept and upvote if my answer helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've got GIT installed on a server that *you* (and whoever else you choose) can SSH, you should already be able to access the server and control who accesses it. Meaning, that you're most likely seeing the results of Git being configured to ssh your own server.

Comment: I am not talking about Github. I have the repository on my own server and when I do git clone user@IP on my local computer I can successfully clone the repo without being asked for any password.

Comment: Does ssh to the server ask you for a password?  Sounds like not.  In which case, git is just working off the same pre-configured access.

Comment: Edited the post to be more relevant to what you're asking. Hope it helps.